# Ruby to return my entries alphabetically works for all but my first entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

This is what it looks like.

```
word = 'word'
words = []


puts 'enter some words, man. ill tell em to you in alphabetical order.'
puts 'when your\'re done, just press enter without typing anything before.'
puts ''
word = gets.chomp
        while word != ''
        word = gets.chomp
        list = list.push word
    end
    puts ''
    puts 'Your alphabetically ordered words are:'
    puts list.sort
    puts ''
```

Again, this works, except for the first word I submit to it. Any hints or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Now it will work

```
word = gets.chomp
while word != ''
  list = list.push word
  word = gets.chomp
end
```

In your case, before pushing the first `word` to `list`( when you just entered into the `while` loop), you are calling again `Kernel#gets` and *assigned* it to `word`. That's why you lost the first word, and from that *second* one you started to pushing the *words* into the array.

Comment: More idiomatic would be `list << word`.

Comment: @glennmcdonald I basically focused on the problem that OP asked. Not the code improvement.. This is very simple code which can be written in many way as I believe.. But thanks for mentioning the method.

Answer (score 1):

Compare with functional approach:

```
sorted_words =
  (1..Float::INFINITY)
    .lazy
    .map { gets.chomp }
    .take_while { |word| !word.empty? }
    .sort
```

Comment: Given that half the functional bits of this are overhead caused by trying to do the while loop functionally, I think this comparison is not in the functional approach's favor!

Comment: @glennmcdonald Given that half of `while` loop implementation is an overhead caused by trying to do `goto` functionality, it's not in favor of `while` loop too :) Readability is a different matter. First 3 lines should be a library method, e.g. `iterate { gets.chomp }`, compare it then.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this cleaner if you realize that assignment returns the assigned value.

```
list = []
until (word = gets.chomp).empty? do
    list << word
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way your program can be rewritten, perhaps in a little more intuitive and expressive way:

```
word = 'word'
list = []

puts 'enter some words, man. ill tell em to you in alphabetical order.'
puts 'when your\'re done, just press enter without typing anything before.'
puts ''
keep_going = true
while keep_going
  word = gets.chomp
  keep_going = false if word.empty?
  list = list.push word if keep_going
end

puts ''
puts 'Your alphabetically ordered words are:'
puts list.sort
puts ''
```